# How to undo the sync to get the files in local repo back?

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I'm very new to github and I started using it a few weeks ago for my uni group project.

The problem that I'm having is:
There is a remote repo on github where everyone in the group is using.
I do have a local repo on my laptop, where I've worked my part of the project.
I recently committed and synced the updates that I made to github using desktop app for mac.
I got a few errors and the sync failed. 
After that when I looked at the files that I have locally, they got overwritten by the ones from the git(non-updated version) and all of my work are gone.

Can you please help me on what I should do to receive the files that I had locally? Is there any way that I can undo that last sync. I found a few suggestions online, but since I'm not sure which one to use, I don't really want to mess up the files anymore.

Thanks

Comment: "There is a remote repo on github where everyone in the group is using" and people the "group" cant help you with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Nearly) All changes made to git repositories can be undo. We don't know the commands you entered but enter it at Google for a specific solution.

You proberly have to use something like:

```
$git rebase
```

Comment: I just realized that I reverted the last commit with the updates(in the desktop app for mac). Would I be able to get my updates back, if I undo the revert? If so, shall I use 'reset' or 'checkout'(just what I found out from a little search on google)? 

Thanks